# How to set a Stellar node to a watcher node?

Tags: stellar-core

I have seen your support docs, it shows me the config file which is to set a public network or testnet node, but it looks like a full validator. Now I want to set it to "Watcher" mode, but I can't find any examples or tutorials. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to set `NODE_IS_VALIDATOR` as `false` in config file to make a node a non-validating observer as stated [here](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/1812c4fc355cc1d878ad8e2bb62352f4e28cd2ea/docs/stellar-core_example.cfg#L203).